# Formatting currency or double for Android API level 15 and above

Tags: java, android

I want to format a number in `Android` (or `Java` for that matter) say

```
12345.67
```

to

```
12,345.67
```

But that it will work with lower API level, namely, from API level 15 and up.

I tried **NumberFormat** `NumberFormat.getInstance().format(myNumber)` or `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(myNumber)` to no avail. Also I tried **DecimalFormat** without success also, that is, it will give you a warning `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 15)` which basically means that although my code will work with phone running on API level 24 but not with older version of Android that uses at least API level 15.

So, what would be my recourse? I don't want to use by the way a utility function just for this but preferably a method from a library. Also `System.out.format()` is out of the question, since I want to show it using `Toast`.

Comment: did you tried with regex

Comment: @VivekMishra I'll give it a try. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I thought it was something that I have to make a special utility function.

It was simply a `String.format()` method did the trick.

```
Double num = 12345.67;
String formatted = String.format("%,.2f", num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat` from `java.text` to work on `Minimum API`below 21

```
#import java.text
....
double num = 123456.78;
String newValue = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have used this code it works on API 17(4.2.2).So i think it should work on API 15 and above.

```
  public static String Round(String Rval, int Rpl) {

    DecimalFormat df = null ;//("#.00");
    String finalStr = "";

    if(Rval.contains(".")){
        String [] inputArr = Rval.split("\\.");
        String newValue = "";
        /*if(inputArr[1].length() == 1){
            inputArr[1] = inputArr[1] + "0";
        }else if(inputArr[1].length() >= 2){
            inputArr[1] = inputArr[1].substring(0,2);
            //inputArr[1] = String.valueOf(Math.round(Integer.parseInt(inputArr[1])));
        }*/

        int length = inputArr[0].length();
        if(length == 7){
            df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else if(length == 8){
            df = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else if(length == 9){
            df = new DecimalFormat("##,##,##,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else if(length == 6){
            df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else if(length == 5){
            df = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else if(length == 4){
            df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }else{
            df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
            newValue = df.format(Double.parseDouble(Rval));
        }

        finalStr = newValue ;//+"."+ inputArr[1];

    }else{
        finalStr = Rval + ".00";
    }
    return finalStr;


}
```

I have checked on my device right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sagar. But `DecimalFormat` does not allow at least API level 15 as min. I'm using **Android Studio 2.2** by the way.

Comment: @Edper ok thanks for your reply.Please provide the solution if you get.Happy coding.